Bitcoin Hex private key
Is it possible to generate a wallet on the Bitcoin main-net without having the number "80" for main net added at the beginning and the double SHA at the end?
I have tried using a random HEX without it having the number "80" at the beginning and the double SHA at the end and it seems I can generate a wallet on the Bitcoin main-net, or this rule only applies to WIF private keys?
